# What steps should I take to make sure Mariadb master is unreachable?

Tags: linux, networking, mariadb

In case of mariadb master is unreachable, what are the checks to make sure my master is really unreachable before going for failover. We use CNAME to connect to master host. So what are the network checks we can perform to absolutely make sure the server is really down.

example- different  server (with different service & in different AZ) may/may not be able to reach to the server. So want to make sure.

Comment: Telnet to port 3306 using the IP address.